# Intersection of two irreducible real algebraic sets of dimension $n-1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have two distinct irreducible real algebraic sets $M_1$ and $M_2$ which have both dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Can I be sure that their intersection has dimension at most $n-2$?

Comment: At least you should require they are distinct, otherwise the intersection has dimension $n-1$

Comment: Yes, of course I suppose that they are distinct. Otherwise it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If $M_1=M_2$, then no.  Otherwise, what does irreducibility tell you about $M_1 \cap M_2 \subset M_1$?

Comment: That is my problem. I don't know if irreducibility tells me something about $M_1 \cap M_2 \subseteq M_1$...

Comment: If $A\subset B$ are irreducible sets of the same dimension, what can we say about them?

Comment: Again, I don't know. Do you know it or are you asking me?